# Good Django apps source code to read

Tags: python, django, open-source

I just created my first Django app. But I felt like most of my code is not well designed/organized. I was wondering what Django apps you guys would recommend I read/study to see how apps should be created (I'm pretty new to Django though, so understanding huge apps might be a little hard for me).

Thanks

Comment: A good question.  The organization aspect is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792894/django-code-organization or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348548/what-is-a-good-way-to-package-django-apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [django by example tutorials](http://lightbird.net/dbe/) to be useful to work through when starting out with django. There is a good range of different applications to work through.

Answer (score 1):

Something quite simple but clean might be [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration) to take a look at from a code perspective. Other options include looking at the [django source code](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk) itself as that will show you how stuff is linked up within Django - and also helps with understanding how parts tie together.